# Laravel: Show data WHEREIN 'Imploded Id' With Array

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have table students

```
+====+=========+===========+
| id | program | full_name |
+====+=========+===========+
| 1  | 2|4|7   | Lucas     |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 2  |    1    | Adam      |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 3  |   4|5   | Eve       |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

and
**$val = array(4,7,10);**
I want to show 'id' and 'fullname' where 'program' in $val.

I have tried this in Controller:
**$val = array(4,7,10);**
**return DB::table('students')->whereIn(explode('|','program'), $val)->get();**

The return is (id:1, full_name:Lucas) and (id:3, full_name:Eve).
Offcourse it does not work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` in your query

```
$val = array(4,7,10);

return DB::table('students')
    ->where('program','like','%'.implode('|',$val).'%')
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find_in_set` of sql

```php
$val = array(4,7,10);

return DB::table('students')
     ->whereRaw("find_in_set(implode('|',$val),replace('|',',',program)")
    ->first();
```

`find_in_set` by default search by `,` but with the help of `replace()` function we can search

ref link https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/